# Web3.py uniswap is status :0 with swapExactTokensForTokens

Tags: uniswap, web3.py, python

I've been testing swap function with python web3.py on python3. But it is having only status : 0 on receipt. I have tried to use amountin and amountout from getAmountsOut function but it is same.

````
approve = tokenContract.functions.approve(ROUTER_ADDRESS, am).buildTransaction({
        'from': SENDER_ADDRESS,
        # 'gas' : 250000,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('40', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SENDER_ADDRESS),
        # 'value':0
    })

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
        approve, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)
    tx_token = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

    print("approved : " + web3.toHex(tx_token))

    receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(
        tx_token, timeout=30000, poll_latency=0.1)
    
    amount = routerContract.functions.getAmountsOut(am,[TOKEN_ADDRESS,TARGET_ADDRESS]).call()
    print(amount)

    swap = routerContract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        web3.toWei('0.0001', 'ether'),#am,
        0,
        [TOKEN_ADDRESS,TARGET_ADDRESS],
        SENDER_ADDRESS,
        (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
    ).buildTransaction({
        'from': SENDER_ADDRESS,
        # 'value': web3.toWei('0.0001','ether'),
        'gas': 250000 ,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('60', 'gwei'),
        'nonce':  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SENDER_ADDRESS),
    })

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
        swap, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)
    tx_swap = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

    print(web3.toHex(tx_swap))

    print("Wait...")
    time.sleep(5)
    receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(
        tx_swap, timeout=30000, poll_latency=0.1)
    print(receipt)```

This is transaction link from my swap testing : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x995ca7515fa7e2afe429cf248d772121aaeb456088b2fd674dd30b5816a2a33b
Thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

From the txs history on Etherscan, it seems like all the code you ran were executed successfully.(BTW you are developing on Mainnet? WOW.)

On etherscan, [your swap transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x908175268f74f3f99c3eb417f1f3976a73cfa1a7e3cae7a2d91a893a98b945bc) failed with this error: "Fail with error 'UniswapV2: K'".

From this [doc](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/common-errors#:%7E:text=In%20essence%2C%20the%20%E2%80%9CK%E2%80%9D,result%20the%20transaction%20is%20reverted.) it stated that:

> In essence, the “K” error means that a trade was attempted that somehow left the trading pair with less reserves than should be there, and as a result the transaction is reverted.

The documentation listed a few causes of this error. IMO it is likely to be caused by not setting aside “fee on transfer” tokens.

You can try to replace `swapExactTokensForTokens` with [swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapexacttokensfortokenssupportingfeeontransfertokens) function.

```
function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
  uint amountIn,
  uint amountOutMin,
  address[] calldata path,
  address to,
  uint deadline
) external;
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: I tried with swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens, but same issue. this is transaction history link : https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf565a6a7270aa679409d5779907b7cc43a6d3e59a1787efd2af833340c6792f1

Comment: You approved 414998989012(12 digit) token and swaped 100000000000000(15 digit) token.

Comment: how can i check it? and how i can fix it? sorry. i am first with this swap using python.

Comment: Oh, they are on Etherscan. On the transaction page, click more details -> input data-> decode input data. 

All the information is there.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think calling your swap function with the amount you approved may just work.

Comment: just tried to swap 12 digits with web3.toWei('0.0000001', 'ether')
but still issue 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x37e53ac50bca10583b388f4c89a588290d66d5b2fcfb792cc17c4ea2dba0e97f

Comment: This transaction revert can be due to many reasons since there is no error message now. I don't want to waste your gas fee here.  My last bet is trying to swap the token at a lower amount, with high approval.

Comment: Maybe can try to set the approval to be ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff ?

Previous successful swaps did this so I guess this may work.

Comment: swap is working well. but i see sometimes "nonce too low" issue

Comment: You get that error when the nonce of current tx is lower or equal to the last successful tx.